# How to access my desktop MongoDB from EC2 Linux?

Tags: mongodb, networking, amazon-ec2, portforwarding

I have MongoDB installed on my desktop, using which I have developed a web application. I want to now deploy this webapp on an EC2 linux instance and test it. I don't want to setup another mongoDB on the EC2 separately, rather use the one on my desktop. I understand that it is not that simple to put my ip and mongo port and just connect.

I have added port-forwarding settings on my router like this -

[image]

[image]

Also I have opened my firewall for this port by adding an inbound rule.

Yet I'm not able to connect. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is bindip set to?

Comment: bindIp: 127.0.0.1

Comment: You need to fix that.

Comment: Ok, so I shall set it to my Ipv4?

Comment: Set to your computer's network address.